# Create a bash file to run R script on windows 10

Tags: r, bash

This is a new idea that I want to try out, I have a main R file that sources different scripts to process data but now I want to create a bash file(.sh) to be able to run this main R file once its clicked instead of opening the scripts on Rstudio..
Here is a sample of file I have created

```
#!/bin/sh

MAIN_FILE_LOCATION=path to file/main.R
R --slave --no-save --no-restore -f "$MAIN_FILE_LOCATION"
#!/bin/sh
echo "sleeping for 1 minute."
sleep 1m
echo "verification complete"
```

This is not running the file *main.R* as expected,...It says no command when the bash file is clicked.My question is how can I create a bash file(.sh) on windows 10 that can run an R script saved on a different file? kindly help

Comment: Wrong and duplicated shebang

Comment: how is it so....Kindly expound

Comment: I don't understand "wrong", but "duplicated" is both correct and (if I understand) not a factor, as it is "merely a comment". Perhaps mostly a comment about style? (I will say that you tagged [tag:bash] but are running the bourne shell `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`, perhaps that's the "wrong" part?)

Comment: If you intend R to run the script file and then exit, would it be better to run `Rscript` instead of `R`? I don't know that that would be causing problems.

Comment: If your only purpose for the shell script is so that you can double-click on an icon to run the R script without opening the RStudio IDE, then how about making a windows shortcut of `"/path/to/Rscript" "/path/to/main.R"`?